# Interpreting F1 2012 UDP packets in Python

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, udp, game-engine

I am working on a project where in game telemetry data from F1 2012 is interpreted by Python and sent to an Arduino to display as a physical dashboard.

F1 2012 sends the data via UDP packets at address 127.0.0.1, port 20777.

I have a simple python program that reads the incoming packets:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 20777

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print ("Message:" data)
```

This outputs messages such as:

```
b'\xce\xb3T@\x00\x00\x00\x001K\xa7E\xa0\xf1\xf0\xbc\xa1\xc6\x13\xc4OY\x0b\xc3\xd5\xbf.D\xca\xe2\xc2;\xb0\x9109\xf0\x19\xbd\xbb\xdd8\xbb:q\x19M\xbf\x81t.933\x19\xbf\x1e,\x19\xbf\xc2\x82\x9d\xbc\x9c\x0fM?\xa2#H\xbc\xd6\x16x\xbe\x92hr\xba:\xa8\x88=X\xd7&?q$\xc7>\x82w#><\xe9\x1d>w\xc9\xb8\xa7Bh\x010\x00\x00\x00\x00kr\xb7\xaf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x80?\x96z\x98\xb9!f\x849\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8d\x8b5C'
```

I know this is a rather long output but it contains 38 parameters about the car which refresh 60 times a second. These are outlined in [this website](http://www.robertgray.net.au/posts/2012/3/connecting-to-codemasters-f1-telemetry-feed#.U-omKmOr-Yk) by someone working on a similar project.

I have looked for similar questions on stackeoverflow with outputs from UDP similar to mine and I was informed that the data had to be unpacked with a suitable format.

Reading [this website](http://potter-online.co.uk/2012/01/31/126/), it seem that the data in the packets are all float types in C so I modified my original code in Python.

```
import socket
import struct

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 20777

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    output = struct.unpack('f', data)
    print ("Message:", output)
```

Unpack is given the format 'f' to assign the format of the incoming data based on information from this page: [docs.python.org/3.2/library/struct.html#format-characters](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/struct.html#format-characters)

This now produces the error:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 4
```

I believe now that I am at a dead end and I do not know how to proceed.

Please help.

Comment: A non-native size will eliminate padding, i.e. `=<>!` before the format string, e.g. `=f`. This is assuming that your data is less than 4 bytes.

Comment: It also looks like you're unpacking multiple values at once, which would be more than 4 bytes and therefore doesn't fit in the C struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says: `struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 4`, you need to pass 4 bytes at a time.

Modify your code to send 4 bytes a time

```
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    # data is 1024 length bytearray, break into 4 bytes and get the output
    output = struct.unpack('f', data[0:4]) # 4 bytes at a time
    print ("Message:", output)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works very well. Your solution is able to output the first parameter as listed in my second link which is "time"(i.e. the elapsed time since the telemetry session had started.) Now I know that each parameter is four bytes I can adjust values so that parts of the read data can be unpacked for the parameters I wish to use. For example, to read the value of the current gear which is the 34th parameter, I would use data[136:140].